# Cron jobs have stopped working due to PAM

Tags: centos, cron, pam

My cron jobs have stopped working on my CentOS 7 server. The server is running WHM/cPanel.

It seems like it is an issue with PAM service because in /var/log/secure I can see the following errors when the cron jobs try to run:

```
Jun 24 10:45:01 server1 crond[22400]: pam_access(crond:account): auth could not identify password for [root]
Jun 24 10:45:01 server1 crond[22404]: pam_access(crond:account): auth could not identify password for [admin]
Jun 24 10:45:01 server1 crond[22400]: pam_localuser(crond:account): auth could not identify password for [root]
Jun 24 10:45:01 server1 crond[22402]: pam_access(crond:account): auth could not identify password for [root]
Jun 24 10:45:01 server1 crond[22405]: pam_access(crond:account): auth could not identify password for [admin]
Jun 24 10:45:01 server1 crond[22400]: pam_localuser(crond:account): auth could not identify password for [root]
```

Similarly /var/log/cron.log is showing that PAM is failing:

```
Jun 24 12:40:01 server1 crond[26129]: (admin) PAM ERROR (Authentication information cannot be recovered)
Jun 24 12:40:01 server1 crond[26129]: (admin) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication information cannot be recovered)
Jun 24 12:40:01 server1 crond[26130]: (admin) PAM ERROR (Authentication information cannot be recovered)
Jun 24 12:40:01 server1 crond[26130]: (admin) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication information cannot be recovered)
Jun 24 12:40:01 server1 crond[26125]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication information cannot be recovered)
Jun 24 12:40:01 server1 crond[26125]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication information cannot be recovered)
Jun 24 12:40:01 server1 crond[26127]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication information cannot be recovered)
Jun 24 12:40:01 server1 crond[26127]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication information cannot be recovered)
Jun 24 12:40:01 server1 crond[26131]: (admin) PAM ERROR (Authentication information cannot be recovered)
Jun 24 12:40:01 server1 crond[26131]: (admin) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication information cannot be recovered)
```

I've tried the following with no success:

- Rebooting the server
- Restarting the cron service
- Editing /etc/security/access.conf to ensure that root is allowed access to the cron
- cron.allow is non-existent and cron.deny is empty so that shouldn't be the
  problem
- Disabling SELinux and rebooting
- Changing root password to ensure it's not an expiry issue
- Checked /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow for passwords of both root and admin user
- Removed all cron jobs except a simple one to write to a text file every minute. This cron job also did not work so it's not related to the jobs in the cron.

Please help as I'm not sure what else to do to fix this problem. It's worth noting that this issue started on June 21 and no changes were made to the server when it began occurring.

Comment: Where either users' passwords changed recently? Can you verify the passwords for `root`, and `admin` in both `/etc/passwd`, and `/etc/shadow`? In `/etc/passwd`, there should be an `x` for the password field, and in `/etc/shadow` there should be a big long hash.

Comment: @LucasRamage Yes the passwords are there for both users in both files you mentioned. I changed the root password to ensure it wasn't a password expiry issue

Comment: Were any relevant system packages updated just before or on June 21st? And, could you check if any file inside `/etc/pam.d/` was recently changed?

Comment: @Edward I checked the files inside that folder and nothing was changed recently. It's possible that WHM did some upgrades but nothing was changed or upgraded manually. I know the exact timestamp the problem began as I can see it in the logs. I'm looking for which files changed around this time.

Comment: Here is the log from when it all began: https://imgur.com/a/eRwAPMm

Comment: I have discovered that the system rebooted at that time and then the problem started about 10 seconds after

Comment: I am having this same issue as of yesterday as well. I'm also running Centos 7. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: What happens if you run this WITHOUT the cronjob? (running manually)

Comment: @user3200708 I haven't found a solution yet. Are you running WHM/cPanel?

Comment: @DarenRobinson The jobs inside the cron run fine when run manually called. I have tried removing all cron jobs and just leaving a simple cron job to write to a text file every minute but it also will not run.

Comment: I have the same issue, reported to cpanel support, not receive update yet. Other people reported same issue in cpanel official forums

Comment: In your logs, I see multiple `pam_succeed_if(crond:account): unrecognized option` lines. That would point to a PAM configuration error of some sort. Can you isolate those lines from your PAM configuration and show us that file?

Comment: @Edward Thanks for the reply. I already tried that unfortunately. I commented out some lines that were causing those "unrecognized" lines. Those errors do not occur anymore but it still complains about 'pam_access(crond:account): auth could not identify password for". See here: https://imgur.com/a/GRoc7Qv

Comment: Also I have another system with CentOS7 and the files are identical. So I don't think it's the config files. Could be the PAM lib though.

Comment: I am comparing this to a stock CentOS 7 system and the only thing standing out is the `pam_hulk.so` PAM module, which is a part of CPanel (`cphulkd` process as Google tells me). Is there any way you could try disabling that piece of software in the panel config and see where that leads you?

Comment: @Edward I tried that yesterday. But I tried it again by disabling cPHulk Brute Force Protection in WHM and also commenting out pam_hulk.so line. The result is the same unfortunately.

Comment: Then I am at a loss. Would you please post the answer/solution you get from CPanel here when (if?) you get it?

Comment: @Edward I am checking /usr/lib/security and /usr/lib64/security folder for the pam files. It seems like pam_systemd.so as well as some other SO files were changed recently. If I had to guess then I'd say that was the problem.

Comment: I have managed to get around the issue temporarily for now as I was very desperate to get the cron jobs working again. I commented out any references to pam_access.so, pam_succeed_if.so and pam_localuser.so which you can see here: https://imgur.com/GnB9rqc

Comment: according to cpanel support, the server might be hacked through EXIM vulnerability. Check the file /lib/libgrubd.so and /etc/ld.so.preload, those files should not exist. https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/281592107ff9dee486898933028430528d643bc7850ab505eaed0be61dae18fd/detection

Comment: @garconcn Thanks so much. That was the issue as reported here:
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cron-jobs-have-stopped-working-due-to-pam.655867

Comment: @pauloz1890, "the system" here automatically locked your question because it attracted a bunch of new users "Answering" with "I have the same problem!" and other low-quality answers that have been deleted. I will open the question back up so that you can self-Answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. It is related to a file called **/lib/libgrubd.so**.

If you're experiencing this issue then check **/etc/ld.so.preload**. If this file contains **/lib/libgrubd.so** (it may be the only line in that file) then remove that line and PAM should start working again. I also removed the **/lib/libgrubd.so** file from the system as it may be associated with a virus as shown [here](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/281592107ff9dee486898933028430528d643bc7850ab505eaed0be61dae18fd/detection).

Still not entirely sure what caused the issue but this was the reason causing PAM to functioning incorrectly. See more info [here](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cron-jobs-have-stopped-working-due-to-pam.655867/).

Comment: Your cpanel server could be hacked due to CVE-2019-10149 Exim, update cpanel to prevent this issue, check https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/CVE-2019-10149+Exim

Comment: Thanks. I was on v78 when it occurred. I already updated to v80 a few days ago. How can I tell if my system was affected in any other way?

Comment: sorry, I don't have more info. If you own the server, it's best to contact cpanel support directly at https://tickets.cpanel.net, they are very good. I am also surprised you had these files even though you are using latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue. What they tell me is this:

> I regret to inform you that this server is compromised at the root level by malware known as ShellBot. This malware is known to cause errors when running the "crontab" command but can potentially cause many other problems including not being able to start certain services.
>
> The presence of /lib/libgrubd.so (which is not normally found on clean systems) is an indication of this malware. This malware is installed in a way that causes it to execute every time a program is run on the server, and can potentially cause aberrant behavior of any process.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I scanned with ClamAV and my system is clean.

Comment: Who is "**they**"?